# There is no second CA certificate found in local keystore error message when starting Java application on SAP BTP

Tags: java, sap-cloud-platform

I deployed a Java application on SAP BTP Neo using the `Java Web Tomcat 8` runtime. The application starts successfully.

However, after startup, there is an entry in the Default Trace logs, and it is an error message (the message reads INFO, but it is categorized as an ERROR message): `INFO: There is no second CA certificate found in local keystore.`

The complete log entry is

```
2021 04 09 06:39:57#+00#ERROR#com.sap.jpaas.service.securestore.local.keystore.internal.LoggerFacade##anonymous#main#####INFO: There is no second CA certificate found in local keystore.
```

The only SAP related dependency in my application is this one:

```
implementation 'com.sap.cloud.connectivity:sap-cloud-connectivity-httpdestination:2.13.0'
```

What does this message mean? Where is it coming from? How can I fix it? Is it even an **error** message, or just an **info**?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at this because of being involved with the [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/). From the problem description and the dependency being used, I see that you're not using the SAP Cloud SDK but probably connectivity libraries from SAP BTP Neo.

The SAP Cloud SDK for Java has its own connectivity abstractions, you can check out our [destination handling here](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/sdk-connectivity-destination-service) and [getting started](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/getting-started) guide to quickly bootstrap your project.

For BTP Neo you can use the following dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>scp-neo</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

If you decide to try the SAP Cloud SDK and will experience any problems you're welcome to create a [detailed issue here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues/new/choose).

Why do you use Neo and not Cloud Foundry by the way? Neo is fazed out and is not recommended for new projects. The build packs and tools can also be slow to update which might cause this missing certificate.